# How do I set up Deja Dup to use encryption?

Tags: 11.10, backup, deja-dup

I noticed Deja Dup is featured heavily as the default backup tool in Ubuntu 11.10. It looks pretty good, and I noticed [elsewhere](http://maketecheasier.com/deja-dup-makes-backup-a-simple-task-linux/2011/03/17) that it seems to support encryption as well. However, the default version in 11.10 seems to have a slightly different interface and does not appear to list any encryption options. Am I missing something? Why doesn't the 11.10-default version support encryption?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

After setting up your backup, press "back up now". A dialog will then appear asking you if you want to password-protect your backup.

[image]

If you do choose a password, your backup is automatically encrypted with that password.